# Getting A subclass Instance From A Collection - Java

Tags: java, collections

Here is a Java programming situation I would like to see any possible improvements.

Class B is a subclass of class A. Some instance of B are in Collection. Based on the type, I can retrieve class B instances from the collection by using instanceof. I, however, can't treat those instances as class B's instances, but class A's only since downcasting isn't allowed. So, I have to get some small pieces of the instances instead by using override getters in class A. There are a few problems with this workaround approach. For example, some getters make no sense in the parent class and the parent class can't be abstract.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Why do you think, you can't do the downcasting? Did you try it? And please post some code demonstrating what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can cast with a subclass, but you have to be sure it's an instance of that subclass.

Comment: I think Collections framework defines class `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` for these type of scenarios --  getters that do not make sense in class `A` should throw it.

Comment: I need to retrieve my question. Yes, the downcasting is applicable in this case if a subclass instance identified by "instanceof". I just wrote a small test code and it works. The cause of my question was a type identifier in our system. It is something like A(){ this.classType=ClassType.A; ...} And I used that to check the class type instead of using instanceof. And I got a casting exception.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without casting would be to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It's a bit verbose in Java, but very extensible...

```
interface Visitor {
    void visit(A a)
    void visit(B b)
}

class BOnlyVisitor implements Visitor {
    public void visit(A a) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void visit(B b) {
        // Do stuff with b
    }
}

interface Visitable {
    void accept(Visitor v)
}

class A implements Visitable {
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

class B implements Visitable {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Our usage scenario doesn't fill in the design pattern intention. An interesting one though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking information to the object in order to do something, ask the object to do it directly. For example, replace

```
int a = object.getA();
int b = object.getB();
int sum = a + b;
```

with

```
int sum = object.computeSum();
```

This way, if the subclass doesn't have a getB() method because it's alsways considered as 0, it can implement the method `computeSum()` using

```
return this.a;
```

Sorry for this stupid example, but that's the idea. Add behavior to your objects rather than making them data structures with getters and setters. If you post a concrete example of what you have to do, I could help more.

Comment: I see what you mean and that is one thing suggested to match out when we use instanceof. But, retrieving an instance of the subclass is on out API.